# How to include a function plot in RegionPlot Mathematica

Tags: plotting, functions, regions, inequalities

I have a RegionPlot graph in Mathematica, which shows the solution to complex inequalities. In the same 2-dimensional space, I would like to plot a function .
Any Help?

Thanks!

##### Update 1

Here is my try which should highlight the region where `t < 3/2 \[Lambda]` and plot the functions. However, the command only shows the Region Plot and not the Plots

```
Show[RegionPlot[t < 3/2 \[Lambda], {t, 1, 2}, {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}], 
 Plot[{thatLP[\[Lambda]], thatLS[\[Lambda]]}, {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}]]
```

##### Update 2

Here is my try which should highlight the region where `t < 3/2 \[Lambda]` and plot the function `t=\[Lambda]`. However, the command only shows the Region Plot and not the Plots

```
Show[{RegionPlot[
   t < 3/2  \[Lambda], {t, 1, 2}, {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}], 
  Plot[t, {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}]}]
```

My Regions and Functions are more complicated, but even this simple example does not work...

Comment: Welcome to the community. I think [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) could be helpful. If you add more detail about your problem, we could help you better.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example for the type of problem you are working with. Include the code (copy and paste-able `InputForm`) for what you have tried.

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks! I am trying with Show. For example, I am writing: 
    Show[RegionPlot[t < 3/2  \[Lambda], {t, 1, 2}, {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}],
  Plot[{thatLP[\[Lambda]], thatLS[\[Lambda]]}, {\[Lambda], 0, 1}]]

Which should highlight the region where t<3/2 \Lambda and Plot the functions: thatLP[\[Lambda]], thatLS[\[Lambda]. However, the command only shows the Region Plot and not the Plots. But if I only ask to Plot them, it works...

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. I am writing: Show[RegionPlot[t < 3/2 [Lambda], {t, 1, 2}, {[Lambda], 17/41, 1}], Plot[{thatLP[[Lambda]], thatLS[[Lambda]]}, {[Lambda], 0, 1}]] Which should highlight the region where t<3/2 \Lambda and Plot the functions: thatLP[[Lambda]], thatLS[[Lambda]. However, the command only shows the Region Plot and not the Plots. But if I only ask to Plot the function, it works...

Comment: If possible, please edit and add the definitions of your function (`thatLP` and `thatLS`) so that we can reproduce the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Show" take its options from the first plot. To override this, you must specify the option in "Show". In this case, you must specify "PlotRange":

```
Show[{RegionPlot[t < 3/2 \[Lambda], {t, 1, 2}, {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}],
   Plot[\[Lambda], {\[Lambda], 17/41, 1}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]